# Browserify define global modules in require

Tags: browserify, require

Is there any way to define a folder/file as a global module in browserify?
E.g:

```
var foo = require('../../../bar/');
```

OR

```
var foo = require('../../../bar/index.js');
```

to be

```
var foo = require('bar');
```

OR

```
var foo = require('bar/index.js');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding a browser field in your `package.json` file :

```
"browser": {
    "bar": "../../../bar/index.js"
}
```

Then you have to import it by `import 'bar';` in your main app file.

After that you can use it as a global module

```
var foo = require('bar');
```